# Include leading zeros of a 32 bit variable, sent over serial port on Arduino Uno board

Tags: c, arrays, serial-port, arduino

i want to send a long variable over the serial port. This code is working 
as pure C code:

```
long var = 1000000;
char arr[32];
sprintf(arr,"%.8X",var);
printf("%s",arr);
```

wich produces the desired output 000F4240

However on the Arduino i cannot get the equivalent code working correctly

```
long var = 1000000;
char arr[32];
sprintf(arr,"%.8X",var);
Serial.print("%s",arr);
```

This always results in 00004240, neglecting the MSB and 3rd byte.

Thanks for all your time and help!!!

Comment: %X is not the proper format specifier for a variable of type *long*, use %lX (ell as in long).

Comment: Hello Hans, i tried sprintf(arr,"%.8lX",var); but i get the same output. I suppose i m mixing something up  with the sizes. But the size of a long on this processor is 4 byte

Comment: A good pure C compiler would warn that `long var = 1000000; ... sprintf(arr,"%.8X",var);` is a problem as the format specifier does not match the type.  Recommend enabling all warnings or get a better pure C compiler.

Comment: Suggest `sprintf(arr,"%08lX", (unsigned long) var);`

Comment: It appears you have an Arduino with an Atmel processor, the size of an *int* is 2 bytes.  Which is why you got 4240 when you used %X, it assumed you passed an *int*.  It may well be that Arduino doesn't support %lX.

Comment: Hi Chux the cast is working! I am using the gcc; now with +Wall flag  and i get   the warning msg: "%X expects unsigned int but argument 3 has type long int". The Arduino embedded compiler was not so forgiving and cut of the last two bytes

Comment: Hi Hans. Yes correct and the   the %lX flag is working with the cast

Answer (score 0):

seems that the arduino's implementation of sprintf only converts in hexadecimal representation only an `int` number, not a `long`...
But I'm not sure...

Strange... [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49662/arduino-why-does-serial-printlnint-hex-display-4-bytes) is the inverse